# My enter key doesn't work in javascript wix

Tags: javascript, button, key, enter

I am doing a to do list in wix.com using javascript.
Now I want to get the text that the user have entered with a button which works great and with the enter key as well which doesn"t work and I have no idea why.

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';

async function addNewTask() {
  const taskTitle = $w('#taskInput').value;
  
  if (taskTitle.length !== 0) {
    const newTask = {
      title: taskTitle,
      completed: false
    }
    
    await wixData.insert('Tasks', newTask);
    $w('#taskInput').value = '';
    await $w('#tasksDataset').refresh();
  }
}

export async function taskInput_keyPress(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    await addNewTask();
  }
}

export async function addTaskButton_click(event) {
  await addNewTask();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You value seems to be a hidden one, you can give it a try.

`if (event.key === "Enter") { await addNewTask().show(); }`

Comment: I don't really know why it doesn't work since it's on wix It is probably diffeence somehow

Comment: I've updated the answer, pls let me know if it works.